# Doubly Linked List to JSON

Tags: c#, json, data-structures, json.net, doubly-linked-list

I've a three dimensional structure ... actually a doubly linked list with six nodes i.e. left, right, up, down, in, out. if one node is on the right side of other then that node will be defiantly on the left side of the first one. like

[image: 2D sample of 3D actual data struture]

Actually this is a 3D structure, but for understanding purposes, I've given a 2D example.
Now I've to convert it in JSON format, to send this data through WCF to a client, but as it contains loops so it couldn't be converted to JSON. I've these questions

1. Can this type of doubly linked list be converted to JSON?
2. Is there another way to do that?
3. Any Other recommended Data Structure? If this is impossible using Doubly Linked List.

I'm using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to handle JSON.

My class is

```
public class Node
{
    public Document document = null;

    public Node left = null;
    public Node right = null;
    public Node up = null;
    public Node down = null;
    public Node inside = null;
    public Node outside = null;
}
```

Comment: You can give each node an ID and use it to serialize/deserializethe nodes: `[{Id=0, Right=1}, {Id=1, Left=0}]`. A similar option is to have a collection of nodes, and a collection of vertices (that is probably better if the connections are undirected).

Comment: You mean I should go for graph data structure?

Comment: You already *have* a limited graph data structure (`Node` is your terminology). It depends on how you represent it - the data is the same data. (for example, you can also go with a 3D array and no edges at all)

Comment: Exactly, you are right bro it is a graph with 6 undirected edges... 3D array was my first preference but problem is that I've to start populating data from middle and move away towards corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json.Net can handle reference loops if you set the `PreserveReferencesHandling` option in the settings.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootNode, settings);
```

This setting will cause the JSON to be written with special `$id` and `$ref` properties which allow the JSON to be deserialized back to the original references, assuming you are using Json.Net to deserialize on the client side.  With this in place you should be able to use your existing object structure with no problem.

Demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Node center = new Node { Name = "In House" };
        Node north = new Node { Name = "North of House" };
        Node west = new Node { Name = "Front of House" };
        Node east = new Node { Name = "Back of House" };
        Node south = new Node { Name = "South of House" };

        center.East = east;
        east.West = center;

        center.West = west;
        west.East = center;

        east.North = north;
        north.East = east;

        east.South = south;
        south.East = east;

        south.West = west;
        west.South = south;

        west.North = north;
        north.West = west;

        DumpNodes(center);

        Console.WriteLine();

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(center, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        Node node = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(json, settings);

        Console.WriteLine();

        DumpNodes(node);
    }

    private static void DumpNodes(Node startingNode)
    {
        HashSet<Node> seen = new HashSet<Node>();
        List<Node> queue = new List<Node>();
        queue.Add(startingNode);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            Node node = queue[0];
            queue.RemoveAt(0);
            if (!seen.Contains(node))
            {
                seen.Add(node);
                Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
                Look("north", node.North, queue, seen);
                Look("west", node.West, queue, seen);
                Look("east", node.East, queue, seen);
                Look("south", node.South, queue, seen);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Look(string dir, Node node, List<Node> queue, HashSet<Node> seen)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   " + dir + ": " + node.Name);
            if (!seen.Contains(node))
            {
                queue.Add(node);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node North { get; set; }
    public Node South { get; set; }
    public Node East { get; set; }
    public Node West { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
In House
   west: Front of House
   east: Back of House
Front of House
   north: North of House
   east: In House
   south: South of House
Back of House
   north: North of House
   west: In House
   south: South of House
North of House
   west: Front of House
   east: Back of House
South of House
   west: Front of House
   east: Back of House

{
  "$id": "1",
  "Name": "In House",
  "East": {
    "$id": "2",
    "Name": "Back of House",
    "North": {
      "$id": "3",
      "Name": "North of House",
      "East": {
        "$ref": "2"
      },
      "West": {
        "$id": "4",
        "Name": "Front of House",
        "North": {
          "$ref": "3"
        },
        "South": {
          "$id": "5",
          "Name": "South of House",
          "East": {
            "$ref": "2"
          },
          "West": {
            "$ref": "4"
          }
        },
        "East": {
          "$ref": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    "South": {
      "$ref": "5"
    },
    "West": {
      "$ref": "1"
    }
  },
  "West": {
    "$ref": "4"
  }
}

In House
   west: Front of House
   east: Back of House
Front of House
   north: North of House
   east: In House
   south: South of House
Back of House
   north: North of House
   west: In House
   south: South of House
North of House
   west: Front of House
   east: Back of House
South of House
   west: Front of House
   east: Back of House
```

Working fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EojsFA

Comment: do you know if it can deserialize that specialty JSON back to in-memory objects and preserve the references?

Comment: @Matt Yes.  In case you are not convinced, I created a [working demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EojsFA) which creates some nodes, links them with circular references, dumps out the object relationships, serializes the structure to JSON with `PreserveReferencesHandling` set to `Objects`, deserializes the JSON back to objects, and finally dumps out the object relationships of the deserialized structure.  You can see that the references are indeed preserved.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a network. One representation of this is a list of edges. Yours are all bidirectional it seems so it could look like this:

```
[
    {source:"Left Node", destination:"Center Node"},
    {source:"Center Node", destination:"Up Node"},
    {source:"Center Node", destination:"Down Node"},
    {source:"Center Node", destination:"Right Node"},
    ...
]
```

You could spit out Json using a traversal of the network. The specific algorithms depend on the specific network you have. However searching on network should give you all the sample code you need.

Doubly linked list is certainly NOT what you need unless you have an extremely specific network that can be traversed in sequence using each edge once only.

Another possibility is that you are really just dealing with Voxels. That is, all your nodes are just coordinates in a 3d cube. The fact that one voxel is adjacent to another then means there is a connection. So if Left Node is at <1,1,1> and Center Node is at <1,2,1> there is a connection because all the coordinates are the same except for Y which differs by only 1. Storage is simply a list of the existing nodes.

Your question mentions a 3D structure, so there seems to be a Voxel representation if nodes are all at a particular distance. If instead the distances are random then you would need to go the network route.

Comment: Yup you are right these are coordinates in a 3D cube I've to visit the closest possible node in each iteration and moving away from center. @DirkBester
http://s26.postimg.org/o2t8kb0c9/Untitled.png

Comment: All right, then if you need visiting that way you need to implement as a network and do a breadth first traversal starting at the closest node to the center.

Answer (score 0):

Any 3D array (or array of any dimensions for that matter), is essentially a 1D array. You can even think of all arrays being 1D, because a 2D array can be interpreted (logically) as an array of arrays, 3D is an array of arrays of arrays, and so on.

If your structure is like a cubic shape, then it is just a 3D array. It doesn't matter that it is stored in a link list. So to do that, just grab one corner (say low left out), then go through your structure line by line, plane by plane and store objects into a 1D (or 3D) array. Construct it in the same way at the other end.

Your serialization would look something like this (where (x,y,z) is whatever content you have for each node)

```
[(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), (0,0,3), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (0,1,2), (0,1,3), ...]
```

If your structure has an arbitrary 3D shape, then arbitrary pick any node, then view the rest as a tree structure. Each element can have a maximum of 6 child nodes. So let say you pick the "center node", you'd first describe what child nodes it has, then later describe the child nodes of the child nodes, if they have any. Give each node an unique ID to distinguish them. It is important that you describe a node as a child node before you describe the child node of that node, otherwise you'd not be able to construct it at the other end.

Your structure would look like this:

```
[{id=0, left=1,right=2,up=3,down=null,in=4,out=5},
{id=1, left=6, right=0, up=7, down=null, in=8, out=9},
...]
```

You can safely ignore any 2-way info in the link list if you wish, because the second way is redundant.