# Handling circular reference with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

My model class look like follows:

```
public class ModelType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ModelType SuperType { get; set }
    public IEnumerable<ModelType> SubTypes { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to serialize object, but getting `StackOverflowException`. I have tried to call

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

as well as

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

Both calls resulted in `StackOverflowException`. Any idea how to serialize `ModelType` instance?

**EDIT**:

Example of instance, which fails to serialize:

```
{
    Name: "Child",
    SuperType: {
        Name: "Parent",
        SuperType: null,
        SubTypes: [{
                Name: "Child",
                SuperType: {
                    Name: "Parent",
                    SuperType: null,
                    SubTypes: [{Name: "Child", ...}]
                },
                SubTypes: []
        }]
    },
    SubTypes: []
}
```

**EDIT2**:

By further looking into the issue (according to all SO Q&A, setting either `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` or `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` should work) I have found out that

1. Child is unique object instance
2. Child.SuperType (Parent) is unique object instance
3. Child.SuperType.SubTypes[0] (Child) is unique object instance, not a reference to (1.)
4. Child.SuperType.SubTypes[0].SuperType (Parent) is unique object instance, not a reference to (2.)
5. And so on...

I think, something went wrong during the object creation (out of my code) and this created infinite chain of objects. I am not sure if this is even possible to handle just by `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Comment: Added the example of populated object.

Comment: Do you have a full C# repro, something that compiles.

Comment: @Simon Mourier, I am sorry, but can't provide code which compiles, it is too complex (going through entity framework -> getting data entities -> transferring to business entities). But I think I have found the root cause. It is when data entity is transformed to business entity, there is created this endless chain by setting properties of SuperType and SubTypes by Lync query, which is evaluated on the fly while serializing.

Answer (score 8):

Newtonsoft.Json can have the following config

```
 JsonSerializerSettings sets = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
    };

    var ser = JsonSerializer.Create(sets);
```

you might want to do that.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not working for me. Still getting `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @mimo - did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853407/json-net-not-respecting-preservereferenceshandling-on-deserialization

Comment: I have looked at question and tried to use same `JsonSerializerSettings` as in proposed answer, but it was not working for me. Most of the solutions states, that `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` should handle the case, but it is not working in my case.